# Convert nested array of objects to csv in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-csv, nested-object

Below is the data I am getting from the rest api and, I want to convert it into a downloadable csv file in react. I am using the react-csv library.

Data :

```
Data : [
    {
        id:1,
        name: "StudentA",
        OOP: [
            {
                id:1,
                date: '09/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            },
            {
                id:2,
                date: '10/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            },
            {
                id:3,
                date: '11/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: "StudentB",
        OOP: [
            {
                id:1,
                date: '09/10/22',
                ispresent: false
            },
            {
                id:2,
                date: '10/10/22',
                ispresent: false
            },
            {
                id:3,
                date: '11/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name: "StudentC",
        OOP: [
            {
                id:1,
                date: '09/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            },
            {
                id:2,
                date: '10/10/22',
                ispresent: false
            },
            {
                id:3,
                date: '11/10/22',
                ispresent: true
            }
        ]
    }
    
]
```

I need the csv in the following format.

| Name | 09/10/22 | 10/10/22 | 11/10/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StudentA | true | true | true |
| StudentB | false | false | true |
| StudentC | true | false | true |

Can anyone help ??

Comment: help with what?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
formattedData = []
header = ["Name"]

// add Dates to header
Data[0].OOP.forEach((e)=>{
 header.push(date)
})
formattedData.push(header)

// add your data
Data.forEach((element)=>{
   let a = []
   formattedData.push(element.name)
   formattedData.push(element.OOP.forEach((i)=> i.isPresent)
```

})